# What does for @array at the end of a Perl statement mean?

Tags: perl

I saw this code in Stack Overflow, and it worked for me. Please explain it.

```
my @amino_acids = $genetic_codes[8] =~ /[ACGT]/g;
join ',', map qq{"$_"}, @amino_acids;
$codons{$_}++ for @amino_acids;
```

What is the purpose of `for` in this code, I tried looking in perldocs but was not able to get a clear picture of it. What else can be used in place of `for`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It increments the value in `%codons` for the number of times a particular amino acid occurs in `$genetic_codes[8]`.

Written out longhand, the last line is equivalent to

```
for my $acid (@amino_acids) {
    $codons{$acid}++;
}
```

In terms of syntactic categories, `for` in this case is a statement modifier, [documented in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers).

> Any simple statement may optionally be followed by a *single* modifier, just before the terminating semicolon (or block ending). The possible modifiers are:
>
> ```
> if EXPR
> unless EXPR
> while EXPR
> until EXPR
> for LIST
> foreach LIST
> when EXPR
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `for(each)` modifier is an iterator: it executes the statement once for each item in the LIST (with `$_` aliased to each item in turn).
>
> ```
> print "Hello $_!\n" for qw(world Dolly nurse);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for explaining with example, till now I was aware of basic syntax of perl and know about loop structure but never used for in one line so got confused.

Comment: @Sandra You’re welcome. Larry Wall borrowed Perl’s statement modifiers from another language, [BASIC-PLUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC-PLUS).

Answer (score 1):

In Perl

```
foo for bar;
```

is a short way to write:

```
for bar { foo; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` and `foreach` are the same. In a traditional C-style for-loop, that would be written:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#amino_acids; $i++) {
    $codons{ $amino_acids[$i] }++;
}
```

It's an idiomatic way of writing effectively the same thing.

Rather than having a loop iterator ($i) you're just using the values in `@amino_acids` as the loop values.

Comment: I am happy atleast you people explained me a small thing which was confusing me, not like intelligent programmers just giving negative marks to simple question.